# clear input when checkbox is unchecked react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to bind value={this.state.grade} so that I can clear the input text when the checkbox is unchecked, but the problem is I can't alter the input field at all. If I used defaultValue, how to clear the input box then?

http://jsbin.com/lukewahudo/1/edit?js,console,output

```
class HelloWorldComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      grade: 123
    }

  }
  handleInput(e) {
      //clear checkbox
    this.setState({
      grade: null
    })
  }


  render() {
    return (      
      <div>
      <div><input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleInput.bind(this)}/></div>
      <div><input defaultValue={this.state.grade} value={this.state.grade} type="number" name="3" /></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please check my answer below as you can still do this with `defaultValue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes:

**1.** Use `onChange` With input element otherwise it will be **read-only**, like this:

```
onChange={e => this.setState({grade: e.target.value})}
```

**2.** Remove the `defaultValue`.

**3.** Instead of assigning `null` assign blank value `''` when the checkbox is unchecked. Before clearing the field put the check by `e.target.checked` it will **return false** when check box will be unchecked.

Use this:

```js
class HelloWorldComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      grade: 123
    }

  }
  handleInput(e) {
     if(!e.target.checked)
        this.setState({ grade: '' });
  }


  render() {
    return (      
       <div>
           <div><input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleInput.bind(this)}/></div>
           <div><input value={this.state.grade} type="number" onChange={e => this.setState({grade: e.target.value})}/></div>
       </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorldComponent/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: this is strange, the fault should be, checked and the field has value, else the field is empty.

Comment: check the updated answer, you need to put a check inside `onChange` of checkbox, if `e.target.checked` returns false then only clear the input element otherwise skip that part.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is to only have a `defaultValue` and a `onChange` function on both inputs.

You can not use `value` AND `defaultValue` (see the [uncontrolled components documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)).

```
class HelloWorldComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      grade: 123,
    }
    this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
    this.handleNumberChange = this.handleNumberChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleInput(e) {
      //clear checkbox
    this.setState({
      grade: null,
    })
  }

  handleNumberChange(event) { 
    this.setState({ 
      grade: event.target.value,
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (      
      <div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleInput}/></div>
        <div><input defaultValue={this.state.grade} onChange={this.handleNumberChange} type="number" name="3" /></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I took the liberty on binding (this) in constructor (to avoid binding at every render) and to set the `props` in the constructor (because if you don't, you can probably not use props)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `null`, you can set this as *empty* as below. You don't need to change anything unless you need to do.

Please have a look at the working code below,

```js
class HelloWorldComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      grade: 123
    }

  }
  handleInput(e) {
      //clear checkbox
    this.setState({
      grade: ''
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (      
      <div>
      <div><input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleInput.bind(this)}/></div>
      <div><input defaultValue={this.state.grade} value={this.state.grade} type="number" name="3" /></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <HelloWorldComponent/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```